# Substring issues - input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, substring

I'm randomly generating simple math equations and need to get the numbers from the string and convert them into integers so I can add them. However, when I run the program I receive the "input string was not in the correct format" error on the "int N1Q1" line.

Is there something I'm missing? Would there be a better way to extract and convert a number from a string?

```
Question1.Text = Convert.ToString(random.Next(1, 9) + " + " + random.Next(1, 9) + " = ");

string FirstQuestion = Convert.ToString(Question1.Text);

int N1Q1 = Convert.ToInt32(FirstQuestion.Substring(0,1));
int N2Q1 = Convert.ToInt32(FirstQuestion.Substring(5,1));
```

Comment: Yes, do not do this in the first place. Store your numbers as numbers and not in a string. The string is good for presentation (showing the user). In your case you could extend Question with additional properties of type `int` and do the assignment there. Alternatively you can create a wraper and encapsulate the Question type and enrich it with additional members.

Comment: Cause `FirstQuestion.Substring(0,1)` isn't an `Int32` type at all

Comment: `Question1.Text` is already a string, why are you calling `Convert.ToString` on it?

Comment: Igor is right your approach is questionable as a whole. But you could just output the values of your `Substring()`s or look at them in the debugger to see if they're valid integer representations. I'd guess your `FirstQuestion.Substring(5,1)` is actually a space...

Comment: The compiler will automatically convert a number to a string if you concatenate it with one, so you don't need the `Convert.ToString` in the first line of code, and the `Text` property is already a `string`, so you don't need it in the second line either.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different way to go about it, you could make each `random.Next()` call into its own variable, then you wont have to do the conversions.  Something like this:

```
int random1 = random.Next(1,9);
int random2 = random.Next(1,9);
Question1.Text = $"{random1} + {random2} = ";
```

You also don't need to convert `Question1.Text` to a string, because it is already a string. Also, using this method, you already have the random numbers captured as variables, then you wont have to convert them back into integers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are off by one in your substring in N2Q1:

```
int N2Q1 = Convert.ToInt32(FirstQuestion.Substring(4, 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

do not forget to declare at the first place the random as the following

```
Random random = new Random();
```

second, in N2Q1 you calculated wrong, it should be as the following:

```
int N2Q1 = Convert.ToInt32(FirstQuestion.Substring(4, 1));
```